# Warning: Incompatible Pointer Type

Tags: c, pointers, types

Ive been working at this problem for about a week, I have looked up plenty of "incompatible pointer type" warning solutions but I'm still confused as to how I can fix this compile error.

I get an error saying:

```
char_stack_interface.c: In function ‘pop_char’:
char_stack_interface.c:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pop’ from incompatible pointer type
char_stack_interface.c: In function ‘top_char’:
char_stack_interface.c:43: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘top’ from incompatible pointer type
```

This is my code:

char_stack_interface.h:

```
#ifndef _CHAR_STACK_INTERFACE_H
#define _CHAR_STACK_INTERFACE_H

#include "stack.h"

extern status push_char(stack *p_s, char  c);
extern status pop_char (stack *p_s, char *p_c);
extern status top_char (stack *p_s, char *p_c);

#endif
```

stack.h:

```
#ifndef _STACK_H
#define _STACK_H

#include "globals.h"

ABSTRACT_TYPE(stack);

extern status init_stack (stack *p_S);
extern bool   empty_stack(stack *p_S);
extern status push       (stack *p_S , generic_ptr data);
extern status pop        (stack *p_S , generic_ptr *p_data);
extern status top        (stack *p_S , generic_ptr *p_data);

#endif
```

char_stack_interface.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "char_stack_interface.h"
#include "stack.h"

status push_char(stack *p_s, char c)
{
    char *p_c = NULL;
    p_c = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (p_c == NULL)
        return ERROR;

    *p_c = c;

    if (push(p_s, p_c) == ERROR) {
        free(p_c);
        return ERROR;
    }

    return OK;
}
status pop_char (stack *p_s, char *p_c)
{
    char *p_data;

    if (pop(p_s, p_data) == ERROR)
        return ERROR;

    *p_c = *p_data;

    free(p_data);

    return OK;
}
status top_char (stack *p_s, char *p_c)
{
    char *p_data;

    if (top(p_s, &p_data) == ERROR)
        return ERROR;

    *p_c = *p_data;

    return OK;
}
```

Comment: You have to add more information. Better paste the headers (or at least the main type definitions from there) as well as which line you're getting the warning at.

Comment: i just realized like a dummy that i didnt put my error message in there sorry about that i just updated it :)

Comment: @Cka91405: What do the `pop` and `top` prototypes look like?

Comment: i agree with chetan, i would need the `#include "char_stack_interface.h" #include "stack.h"` files as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well whatever the generic_ptr type is, obviously the compiler is not able to automatically cast your 'char *' type into generic ptr type. Try doing an explicit case of your second arg to pop and top e.g.:

pop(p_s, (generic_ptr)p_data)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `generic_ptr` is (as it's usually the case):

```
typedef void* generic_ptr;
```

Then `pop` is:

```
extern status pop        (stack *p_S , void **p_data);
```

And you're calling it like:

```
pop(stack*, char*);
```

Therefore, you're passing a `char*` argument to `void**`, which is from an invalid pointer type. Depending how the pointer is handled in `pop`, you would have to pass a pointer to your pointer and/or explictly tell the compiler how to handle the situation with an explicit cast.

Comment: see im confused because im suppose to copy the code from my textbook and place it into the file and it shows nothing like that in the book. which is making me more confused. :(